# How to select specific fields from pivot table that matches exact values

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

- conversations - I save basic information about the conversation
- users - Infor about user
- conversation_users - table that saves information about which user belongs to which conversation

In my case user "1" wants to get a conversation between him and users: 3, 4, 5. So I'm trying to fetch conversation_id = 12. First I need to find all conversations user "1" belongs to, that is conversation_id "1" and "12".

Next I'm executing `SELECT * FROM conversations_users WHERE conversation_id in (1,12)`. How do I pick rows marked in red rectangle?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this step-by-step approach consider:

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_users
WHERE user_id IN (1,3,4,5)
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

This should work as long as your key for this table is `user_id, conversation_id`

Comment: It works but unfortunately it might get wrong result, for example: `SELECT conversation_id FROM conversations_users WHERE user_id IN (1,2,4,5) GROUP BY conversation_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 3;`
It gives me result 12, based on this table https://prnt.sc/22102en

But otherwise it works if I make sure in the code that COUNT(user_id) matches number of ids in "user_id IN()" condition

Comment: That's the caveat for sure. That count needs to match the distinct number of users you are searching for. You may be able to do something like `HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1,3,4,5)` in which case you can supply the same `IN` list in both places. You could probably supply the `IN` list just once in a subquery on the `users` table and check that distinct counts match between both tables post-join but that may get bring in some other edge cases.

Comment: Unfortuantely it won't work it doesn't give me correct result